# Second WLAN card not available in Kali 2.0

Tags: wireless-networking, pci-express, kali-linux

I recently installed two of the same pcie wireless LAN cards into my HP 2710p computer with Kali Linux 2 installed. I can use one of the cards, but the second card is not available. I cannot find a second wireless LAN entry within my file system nor within the interface selection for Wireshark. Why is the second card not available?

Comment: `dmesg` shows detection? `lspci`?

Comment: @ssnobody I can't find a reference to the second card in either of those outputs. Maybe the card is bad?

Comment: I don't know if it's bad but at the very least it's not being detected. Perhaps try reseating the card. It is unlikely to work if the OS does not detect that it is present.

Comment: @ssnobody It took some searching, but apparently the second slot is whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

One of the two available pcie slots is "whitelisted". The BIOS will not accept the device for an obvious reason.